# Timestamp fields in knex.js migrations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, datetime, knex.js

I'm currently writing migrations for my database (sqlite3) using knex. I'm making "users" table and I want there to be two timestamp fields, `created_at` and `updated_at`. I want them to be notNullable and added by default when inserting a row into table. I can use something like `table.timestamp("created_at).notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now())` but in SQLiteStudio it shows as formatted timestamp YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in UTC timezone (so not my timezone). So I've got 2 questions:

1. How can I set this date to my timezone?
2. Is it possible to set datetime field in sqlite in such way, that when I get it from `SELECT` statement it is returned as Unix Timestamp (integer) and still be shown as formatted date in SQLiteStudio?

This is my migration code:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
        table.increments("_id").primary().notNullable();
        table.text("login").unique().notNullable();
        table.text("given_name").notNullable();
        table.text("family_name").notNullable();
        table.timestamp("created_at").notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.timestamp("updated_at").notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.boolean("is_active").notNullable().defaultTo(true);
    }),
]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) should give some clues.

> Date And Time Functions
>
> SQLite supports five date and time functions as follows:
>
> ```
> date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...) 
> time(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...) 
> datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
> julianday(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...) 
> strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
> ```

I believe the idea is to always store times as UTC, then convert to localtime, using `strftime()` when you want to display the value.

An example using the `localtime` flag with `datetime` is given:

> Compute the date and time given a unix timestamp 1092941466, and
>   compensate for your local timezone.
>
> ```
> SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
> ```

For human readable text you need `strftime()`. It's a bit gnarly but it works. I'm hoping these sorts of queries are possible from knex, which I've never even heard of!